# How to increase virtual memory in Windows 10

Tags: windows, memory, ssd, virtual-memory, adobe-premiere

Premiere Pro is complaining when I import more than 120gb of video. I have 240gb ssd, 10gb RAM. 
When I increase virtual memory to 15GB, max 30GB, I still getting the low memory import error once the memory (checked in system status) reach 10gb.

I was believeing that once I increase virtual memory for 15gb, I will have together 25gb of RAM (yes I know that's not real RAM).

I've resterted PC several times. The hard drive has still around 30gb free space.

Do you know where can be a problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Virtual memory resides on the SSD, you need a much bigger SSD to do this kind of work.

Comment: Agree . One file is half your SSD.

Comment: How much free space do you have on the disk? It seems to me you will need something like 120+120+15 before even saying "Windows".

Comment: Have you tried to disable your pagefile entirely and start Premiere Pro? I know it sounds counter-intuitive to what you're asking, but as the others have pointed out, you're going to need a (much) bigger SSD if you are going to keep working with your current virtual memory setup, so why not think outside of the box, even just for experiment's sake? From what I read here and there, Premiere Pro allows you to decide how much RAM you'll let it play with. Given the size of the files you want to work on, you'll need to invest in new hardware, so why not check if you what you can do with no swap?

Comment: well, the question is than, should I upgrade ssd or ram ?! ... yes, I know both will be perfect, as same as whole new computer... but I'm not a fan of throwing out things which may require just different approach. /////// Once I start import, I still have like 30gb of free space, that's what's makes me think that the ram upgrade might be more useful than ssd. thank you

Comment: You might give Wagnardsoft's Intelligent standby list cleaner. https://www.wagnardsoft.com/content/intelligent-standby-list-cleaner-v1000-released , a quick try. During memory-intensive operations, such as processing *many* documents in Calibre, as well as in games, I've found it allowed things to finish that previously failed.